# Browserify adding multiple files to bundle.js

Tags: javascript, browserify

I want to use Browserify to add a couple files to one bundle. I have one "app.js" file, and a "config.js" file. The config has some connection endpoint info, and at the end has

```
module.exports = config;
```

I'm not good with this stuff, but I am assuming this is needed so it can be referenced elsewhere.

So my app.js file has some requires, like so:

```
var documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;
var config = require("./config");
var url = require('url');
```

I know that with browserify I can do one file like their getting started tutorial by doing something like:

```
browserify app.js --debug | exorcist bundle.map.js > bundle.js
```

I know I have some extra stuff in there, but my question is, wouldn't I also need to include the config.js in there, since it exports some config items that the app.js needs? If so, how would I add both the app.js and config.js into the bundle.js?

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `browserify app.js` in your CLI, Browersify treats `app.js` as the entry point.  Each `require` statement in your code in `app.js` references a library that has some code that is returned via `module.exports`, Browserify traverses these libraries and concatenates all of the Javascript together in the final bundled output `bundle.js`.

By specifying `var config = require("./config");`, you're telling Browersify to look in `./config` for a `module.exports`, return that code and assign to `var config`.

This is a solid, lengthier explanation of what I posted: https://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/how-browserify-works/